# Npm dependencies for plugins

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs

Warning: I have very limited knowledge about NPM dependencies and I'm trying to wrap my head around this coming from the Ruby world.

I'm working on a Chrome extension, using React. At the top of my `content.js` script, I have this:

```
var React = require("react");
var $ = require("jquery");
var moment = require("moment");
```

All works fine with the React app, but now I'm trying to add a datepicker to some fields. I found this component: https://www.npmjs.org/package/react-datepicker. I'd like to try it. So I did:

```
npm install react-datepicker --save
```

And that installed it to my `package.json`. But now at the top of my `content.js` script, how do I require it?

I tried:

```
require("react-datepicker");
```

But that didn't work and throws:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): DatePicker is not defined
```

and then I tried sending it to a variable, but then I was even more confused because I'm not sure I need to reference the output of it later. I really just need to load it and use it in the context of the React app.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the test folder inside their repo :
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

Comment: I've looked at it. It didn't help. This is more about NPM dependencies. The question could really be about any component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, `require('anything')` should have no side effects, so ignoring the result of it makes it useless.

It doesn't load anything into React, it just gives you the component class which you can then use in your components.

```
var DatePicker = require("react-datepicker/react-datepicker");
var React = require("react");

var MyThing = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <div><DatePicker /></div>
  }
});

module.exports = MyThing;
```

Comment: That makes sense. I added `var DatePicker = require("react-datepicker");` and when I compile, I get: `path.js:313
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');`

Comment: @brandonhilkert updated.  The package.json is malformed which is causing require to fail.

Comment: out of curiosity, is it the `main` key that dictates how you reference it? If so, why the extra folder path?

Comment: Ugh, now I get this http://cl.ly/image/1l043k030f1w. Sort of seems like this component might be worth using?

Comment: @brandonhilkert, the pull request has been merged, you can `npm install --save react-datepicker@latest` and it should work.